# undefined method `featured' for Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I try to add a full-text search in my app. With gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.3' and gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.3' for my app. When i try save something in mysql db like:

```
 @post = Post.new
 @post.title = "Theorema"
 @post.save
```

It gives me ROLLBACK and:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `featured' for #<Post:0x00007f018ab005d0>):
```

I am beginer and will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO Oleg.
Have you got an attribute `featured` in your `Post` model?

There is one on the github page of the [gem](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot) you used. 
Maybe you copied it by mistake. Either remove that if you do not need it or add it to posts and migrate.

Can not really tell without seeing your `Post` model.

Comment: Thanks, it solved. Next time I try to be more attentive)